# Erro de sintaxe no PHP comando reset()

Tags: php

Essa sintaxe está incorreta?

```
$impostos[$value['prod']['cProd']]['ICMS']['vicms']=reset($value['imposto']['ICMS'])['vICMS'];
```

minha dúvida é em relação ao comando `reset()` se pode ser usado dessa maneira

Está dando erro ***500 Internal Server Error*** ná minha página PHP

E quando abro com o Dreamweaver ele fica indicando que esta linha está incorreta

Comment: Qual erro? o que está acontecendo?

Comment: o `['vICMS']` deveria estar dentro do parenteses, vc precisa habilitar os erros, assim, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: na verdade está certo dessa forma, porque eu preciso pegar o primeiro item do array e lá dentro pegar o `['vICMS']` então se eu deixasse ele dentro dos parenteses não funcionaria @rray

Comment: `reset($value['imposto']['ICMS']); $impostos .... =  $value .... ['vICMS']` resolve? troque os pontos pelas longas rs

Comment: Depende da versão do seu PHP, se for 5.3 abaixo não aceita isso: `reset($value['imposto']['ICMS'])['vICMS']`

Comment: @gabrieloliveira pior que, a versão que estou usando é a `5.5.9`

Comment: Você pode colocar um trecho do retorno desse array?

Comment: Você tem certeza que o erro está aí nessa linha? O ideal é ativar a exibição de erros para que mostre mais detalhes. No dreamweaver está configurado essa versão do PHP que você está usando?

Comment: Problem solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma dica é ativar a [exibição de erros](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-reporting.php) enquanto estiver desenvolvendo, facilita encontrar os problemas.

Caso queira tentar de uma outra maneira com a função reset(), você pode atribuir o retorno em uma variável e acessar o índice que deseja:

```
$firstElement = reset($value['imposto']['ICMS']);
$impostos[$value['prod']['cProd']]['ICMS']['vicms'] = $firstElement['vICMS'];
```

Comment: Acho que esse é o trecho que você se referiu: `$impostos[$value['prod']['cProd']]`. E nesse caso está correto. Só fica um pouco difícil de visualizar por tantas aberturas e fechamento de colchetes.

Comment: Você pode colocar um trecho do retorno desse array?

Comment: Nesse caso, o $value['prod']['cProd'] porderia ser qualquer valor, como 1. E nesse caso, essa chamada seria assim: `$impostos[1]`. Por isso eu disse que não estava incorreto. Mas para definir o erro o ideal é habilitar a exibição de erros como você disse.

Comment: Problem solved!